Why is iostream not found when importing a C++ library using a Bridging Header in my Swift app project?
I have been using a library written in C in my Swift app project by importing it through an Objective-C Bridging Header.
The library is compiled into a '.a' file, and I can use it by linking the header files.
I tried to link a library that has been rewritten in C++ using the same method, but I am encountering an issue: "'iostream' file not found."
This problem does not occur in a test Objective-C app project created by our internal library team. However, the issue with iostream arises when integrating with Swift.
#ifndef ddddd_Bridging_Header_h
#define ddddd_Bridging_Header_h

#import "../../lib/testlib.h"

#endif

my bridging header file
failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/kimjitae/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ddddd-glmnoqrwdrgarrhjulxjmalpyikr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/ddddd-Bridging-Header-swift_3O89L0OXZ0CPD-clang_188AW1HK8F0Q3.pch' for bridging header '/Users/kimjitae/Desktop/enf4/ddddd/ddddd/ddddd-Bridging-Header.h'
bridging header error
'iostream' file not found
library error

IIRC, you can't use C++ in such bridging headers.

@molbdnilo Then, why is it possible to use the library in an Objective-C app project? Is there no way for me to resolve this?

Probably because the code that uses it is actually Objective-C++.

Issue arises because Swift doesn't natively support C++ headers like iostream. You will need to use Objective-C++ for the integration. Try changing the file extension of your bridging header file from .m to .mm to enable Objective-C++ support, which allows the use of C++ libraries. Ensure that the C++ standard library is also correctly linked in your Xcode project settings.
